# MongoDB UniqueIndex on EmbenddedDocuments

Tags: mongodb, unique-index

I got a little issue with create `unique indexes` on `EmbenddedDocuments`

I have the following schema:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58da1dd3d1f0e80cac0002e2"),
    "slug": "about-us",
    "languages": [{
            "title": "About us",
            "content": "Here is something written about us",
            "language": DBRef("languages", ObjectId("58d29616d1f0e82574007d12"), "XXX"),
            "keywords": [],
            "description": "Here you can find all information about our company"
        },
        {
            "title": "About us",
            "content": "Here is something written about us",
            "language": DBRef("languages", ObjectId("58d29616d1f0e82574007d13"), "XXX"),
            "keywords": [],
            "description": "Here you can find all information about our company"
        },
        {
            "title": "About us",
            "content": "Here is something written about us",
            "language": DBRef("languages", ObjectId("58d29616d1f0e82574007d13"), "XXX"),
            "keywords": [],
            "description": "Here you can find all information about our company"
        },
        {
            "title": "About us",
            "content": "Here is something written about us",
            "language": DBRef("languages", ObjectId("58d29616d1f0e82574007d13"), "XXX"),
            "keywords": [],
            "description": "Here you can find all information about our company"
        }
    ]
}
```

and created the following `indexes`:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "key": {
        "_id": NumberInt("1")
    },
    "name": "_id_",
    "ns": "XXX.pages",
    "v": NumberInt("2")
},
/* 2 */
{
    "key": {
        "slug": NumberInt("1")
    },
    "name": "slug_1",
    "ns": "XXX.pages",
    "sparse": false,
    "unique": true,
    "v": NumberInt("2")
},
/* 3 */
{
    "key": {
        "languages.language.$id": 1
    },
    "name": "languages.language.$id_1",
    "ns": "XXX.pages",
    "sparse": true,
    "unique": true,
    "v": NumberInt("2")
}
```

As you can see in the schema I can create new `EmbenddedDocuments` on a page. But it should give me an error?

I use this command to insert an `EmbenddedDocument`

```
db.pages.update({
    "_id": ObjectId("58da1dd3d1f0e80cac0002e2")
}, {
    "$pushAll": {
        "languages": [{
            "title": "About us",
            "content": "Here is something written about us",
            "language": {
                "$ref": "languages",
                "$id": ObjectId("58d29616d1f0e82574007d13"),
                "$db": "XXX"
            },
            "keywords": [],
            "description": "Here you can find all information about our company"
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors Please replace screenshots with json

Comment: Why you created language.id unique. is it case a language can have one page only? remove unique index from here.

Comment: @AlexBlex excuse me I replaced the images

Comment: @Love-Kesh A page can have multiple languages. But a single page can only have single language once.